# Wordpress Wp_Query search with meta_query and apostrophe in value

Tags: wordpress

I'm doing a Wp_Query with a meta_query value that has ' in the name. For example " Corner's ".
The arguments array for wp_query looks like

```
$location_array = array(
                    'key'     => 'hidden_address',
                    'value'   => stripslashes ( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['adv_location'] ) ),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    'type'    => 'char',
            );
```

But the query returns 0 results when searching for  " Corner's " . For " Corner " returns a correct result.

Comment: Have you checked **1.** what the value in `$_GET['adv_location']` is and **2.** how the apostrophe is being stored in the database? You are using `sanitize_text_field` which should work for plain text so it's likely that is there is other encoding used somewhere along the way.

Comment: Thanks - you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The post meta was saved as Corner's - so the solution is to use htmlspecialchars

```
    $value  =   stripslashes ( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['adv_location'] ) );
    $value  =   htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES );
    $location_array = array(
                    'key'     => 'hidden_address',
                    'value'   =>  $value,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    'type'    => 'char',
            );
```